# How do Ifilter locations with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have js files for map and locations, however, I need to filter the locations between two types of properties. Ideally I would want a box with buttons that the user can click on to show ALL, Property Set One, Property Set Two.

The following code is the html page that calls the map and the toggle.

The .js is the code for the map and markers and there is another file that calls for locations. That code is also included. From what I can tell, I need to add another perimeter to the list of locations to match up to the call out in the html. I just can't figure out how to get the code in the custom-map.js part of the code to recognize the perimeter.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```js
var mapStyles = [{
  featureType: 'water',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#d7ebef'
  }, {
    saturation: -5
  }, {
    lightness: 54
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'landscape',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#eceae6'
  }, {
    saturation: -49
  }, {
    lightness: 22
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'poi.park',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#dddbd7'
  }, {
    saturation: -81
  }, {
    lightness: 34
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'poi.medical',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#dddbd7'
  }, {
    saturation: -80
  }, {
    lightness: -2
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'poi.school',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#c8c6c3'
  }, {
    saturation: -91
  }, {
    lightness: -7
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'landscape.natural',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#c8c6c3'
  }, {
    saturation: -71
  }, {
    lightness: -18
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'road.highway',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#dddbd7'
  }, {
    saturation: -92
  }, {
    lightness: 60
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'poi',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#dddbd7'
  }, {
    saturation: -81
  }, {
    lightness: 34
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'road.arterial',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#dddbd7'
  }, {
    saturation: -92
  }, {
    lightness: 37
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}, {
  featureType: 'transit',
  elementType: 'geometry',
  stylers: [{
    hue: '#c8c6c3'
  }, {
    saturation: 4
  }, {
    lightness: 10
  }, {
    visibility: 'on'
  }]
}];

$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Google Map - Homepage
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createHomepageGoogleMap(_latitude, _longitude) {
  setMapHeight();
  if (document.getElementById('map') != null) {
    $.getScript("assets/js/locations.js", function() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(_latitude, _longitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: mapStyles
      });
      var i;
      var newMarkers = [];
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
        pictureLabel.src = locations[i][7];
        var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        infoboxOptions = {
          content: boxText,
          disableAutoPan: false,
          //maxWidth: 150,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, 0),
          zIndex: null,
          alignBottom: true,
          boxClass: "infobox-wrapper",
          enableEventPropagation: true,
          closeBoxMargin: "0px 0px -8px 0px",
          closeBoxURL: "assets/img/close-btn.png",
          infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        };
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          title: locations[i][0],
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),
          map: map,
          icon: 'assets/img/marker.png',
          labelContent: pictureLabel,
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
          labelClass: "marker-style"
        });
        newMarkers.push(marker);
        boxText.innerHTML =
          '<div class="infobox-inner">' +
          '<a href="' + locations[i][5] + '">' +
          '<div class="infobox-image" style="position: relative">' +
          '<img src="' + locations[i][6] + '">' + '<div><span class="infobox-price">' + locations[i][2] + '</span></div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</a>' +
          '<div class="infobox-description">' +
          '<div class="infobox-title"><a href="' + locations[i][5] + '">' + locations[i][0] + '</a></div>' +
          '<div class="infobox-location">' + locations[i][1] + '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        //Define the infobox
        newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            for (h = 0; h < newMarkers.length; h++) {
              newMarkers[h].infobox.close();
            }
            newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
          }
        })(marker, i));

      }
      var clusterStyles = [{
        url: 'assets/img/cluster.png',
        height: 37,
        width: 37
      }];
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, newMarkers, {
        styles: clusterStyles,
        maxZoom: 15
      });
      $('body').addClass('loaded');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('has-fullscreen-map');
      }, 1000);
      $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');

      //  Dynamically show/hide markers --------------------------------------------------------------

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          if (map.getBounds().contains(newMarkers[i].getPosition())) {
            newMarkers[i].setVisible(true); // <- Uncomment this line to use dynamic displaying of markers

            //newMarkers[i].setMap(map);
            //markerCluster.setMap(map);
          } else {
            newMarkers[i].setVisible(false); // <- Uncomment this line to use dynamic displaying of markers

            //newMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            //markerCluster.setMap(null);
          }
        }
      });

      // Function which set marker to the user position
      function success(position) {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.panTo(center);
        $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
      }

    });
    // Enable Geo Location on button click
    $('.geo-location').on("click", function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        $('#map').addClass('fade-map');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
      } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
      }
    });
  }
}

// Function which set marker to the user position
function success(position) {
  createHomepageGoogleMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.slider.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">

  <title>Zoner | Google Map with Horizontal Search</title>

</head>

<body class="page-homepage map-google horizontal-search-float" id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navigation" data-offset="90">
  <!-- Wrapper -->
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="geo-location-wrapper">
        <span class="btn geo-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span class="text">Find My Position</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- end Map -->

    <!-- Search Box -->
    <div class="search-box-wrapper">
      <div class="search-box-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="search-box map">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#search-form-sale" data-toggle="tab">Sale</a></li>
              <li><a href="#search-form-rent" data-toggle="tab">Rent</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="search-form-sale">
                <div class="nav2">
                  <div class="vertical">
                    <h3><strong>Map Controls</strong></h3>
                    <div>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:$('#map_canvas').trigger('show', '1')" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Build To Suite</a>
                      <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:$('#map_canvas').trigger('show', '2')">Vacant Land</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /#search-form-rent -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.tab-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.search-box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.search-box-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- end Search Box -->


  </div>
  <!-- end Page Content -->

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDkPjUTyDRKXQfvsSsNZRXSow9mIv0ElAc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/infobox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/icheck.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.vanillabox-0.1.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jshashtable-2.1_src.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/tmpl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dependClass-0.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/draggable-0.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.slider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom-map.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  <!--[if gt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <script>
    _latitude = 43.1082213;
    _longitude = -89.3198024;
    createHomepageGoogleMap(_latitude, _longitude);
    $(window).load(function() {
      initializeOwl(false);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var locations = [
    ['3591 Anderson St', "Madison, WI 53704", "$36,000", 43.1205092, -89.3255892, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-McAllenTECcenter.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png",false, "1"],
    ['3398 Lodgeville Road', "Golden Valley, MN 55427", "$28,000", 48.866876, 2.309639, "property-detail.html", "assets/img/properties/property-02.jpg", "assets/img/property-types/apartment.png"],

   
];
```

Comment: Didn't try anything? Show us...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please reduce your example to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. (Note the "minimal.")